# Stop at first match when greedy matching

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to create a mod_rewrite rule to match **first** language from the `Accept-language` header. The header may contain only one language code, but usually contains more than one. I need to match first from my list of *supported* languages.

For example, this is the rule for supported languages: `^.*(sv|ne|nb|pl|en).*$`.

This is example `Accept-language` header: `no-nb, en-US, en`

The problem that I'm facing is that it gives me the last match, which is `en` string. But I need first match which is `nb` in this case.

Here is a regex [fiddle](http://regex101.com/r/uP5dN5/1) that illustrates this issue.

Note that I'm matching only the part of the `no-nb` language code on purpose.

Comment: I can't test it here, but does the usual match-the-least-amount-of-characters `.*?` not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^.*?(sv|ne|nb|pl|no|en).*$
   ^--- Note the '?' to use non-greedy quatifier
```

http://regex101.com/r/uP5dN5/2

Comment: @SiliconMind lol thanks for the tick. It uses to happen but the community is willing to help :)